# Gigya Plugin Google plus application not working

Tags: wordpress, google-api, google-apps, gigya

Thank you in advanced.

We have setup Google Application using this Gigya guide URL: http://developers.gigya.com/010_Developer_Guide/82_Socialize_Setup/005_Opening_External_Applications/16_Google

And we set Client ID and Client secret key on the gigya site settings. there we also setup Linked in and Facebook apps in gigya site.

When we click on the Gigly Google icon in front side (my site) there not calling my own application there call default gigya test application.

What I can do. Please suggest me where we are going wrong.

Other application working(Call) perfectly in my site. But only Google application will not call properly.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If the Gigya test application is being loaded, it means that within the providers configurations under the site settings menu, the client id and client secret have not been setup properly. The Gigya Test application is only loaded in this case.

Please take note of the following pointers:

- Ensure that you click the "Save Settings" button at the bottom of the
  site settings => provider's configurations page in the Gigya
  dashboard every time after you key in the client ID and client
  secret. After you see the "Settings Saved" message highlighted in
  green beside that button, refresh the page to ensure that it has been
  saved.
- There is a difference between the google and google+ (Google Plus)
  login providers when using the Gigya product. If you are making the
  socialize.showLoginUI API call with "googleplus" listed in the
  enabledProviders parameter, do ensure that you key in the client
  id and client secret for the "g+" (in red) provider instead of the
  "g" (in blue) provider under the site settings => provider's
  configurations menu.
- Vice-versa, if you are making the socialize.showLoginUI API call with
  "google" listed in the enabledProviders parameter instead, do ensure
  that you key in the client id and client secret for the "g" (in blue)
  provider instead.
- Ensure that you have turned on the google+ API under the google
  application's 'services' menu in the application's settings within
  your [Google API console](https://code.google.com/apis/console/).

I would also highly encourage you to submit a support request to support@gigya.com and include the Gigya API key of the site which you are having issues with should the problem persist. The Gigya support team would be more than glad to assist you troubleshooting the issue further.

I hope this helps!

=========================================================

Josh

Client Services Team

[Gigya Inc](http://www.gigya.com/) | The Connected Consumer Management Suite

=========================================================